# How to get the value of a specific attribute in XML using C#?

Tags: c#, xpath

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to access a xml node with attributes and namespace using selectsinglenode()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716287/how-to-access-a-xml-node-with-attributes-and-namespace-using-selectsinglenode)

I have an XML:

```
<Root xmlns:XXXlocal="XXXX" schemaVersion="2.7" variant="multiterm">
  <Customers>
    <Customer type="Covered">
      <DataItem name="OpCity" value="" />
      <DataItem name="OpAddress1" value="" />
      <DataItem name="OpAddress2" value="" />
      <DataItem name="OpState" value="MI" />
    <Customer>
  </Customers>
</Root>
```

I need to get the value "MI" from the above XML. Please note that the XML has many different "Customer Types."

How would I go about doing this? I'm having difficulty writing the xPath query to get it.

Comment: Please show your sample code... and effort for searching for similar questions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C#, you can use LINQ/XDocument, and `XPathSelectElement()` to query with xpath:

```
var document = XDocument.Load(fileName);
var namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
namespaceManager.AddNamespace("l", "XXXX");
var val = document.XPathSelectElement("/l:Root/l:Customers/l:Customer[@type='Covered']/l:DataItem[@name='OpState']/@value", namespaceManager).Value;
```

Comment: XPathException was unhandled. Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function.

Comment: Pass the `namespaceManager` to `XPathSelectElement()` as the second parameter. See the updated example.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the namespace `XXXX` is defined as the prefix `x`, this should work...

```
/x:Root/x:Customers/x:Customer[@type='Covered']/x:DataItem[@name='OpState']/@value
```